# Logstash to drop parts of a SNMP field name

Tags: filter, logstash, snmp

I'm using the Logstash SNMP input, and am receiving fields like the following:

`iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.host.hrStorage.hrStorageTable.hrStorageEntry.hrStorageAllocationUnits.1"`

Is there a way I can use a filter to drop everything before hrStorage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mutate filter with the [gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) option. If the part you want to drop is always before `hrStorage.`, you can do something like this:

```
mutate {
  gsub => [ "message", "^(.*)(hrStorage\..*)$", "\2"]
}
```

It uses capturing groups, with the second group grabbing from `hrStorage.` to the end and the first group grabbing the rest. Then we only keep the second in the replace part of the option.